Pycharm doesn't allow me to enter non-ascii characters in files
I am using Pycharm on Ubuntu 20.04.
The problem I have is that pycharm does not allow me to enter characters like ñ, ó, etc. Therefore I have to open another program, for example Mousepad (a text editor program) and enter them.

This is the way that I usually enter those chars in other programs like Mousepad:

I have configured the compose key as the pause key of the keyboard on my system

For example, If I want to enter the ñ key, I press the following combination of keys:
Pause + n + ~
as a result ñ is printed
Of course I could use Ctrl + Shift + U + unicode + Enter if I want too, but I don't use this way normally.

Is there any way to make the compose method from the keyboard work in Pycharm?
I have tried many ways in the configuration without any success

As you can guess, most of us can do it. But you do not provide enough information for us to understand the problem (but also it is difficult for us to ask for more details). How do you enter the non-ascii characters? Check PyCharm settings and search for the key you use, PyCharm may use such keys for other operations: just remove and change. or try different keyboard settings. We assume you can enter such characters on all other programs, right?

Hi!, thanks for comment on my question. I usually enter the non-ascii characters using the Compose key (which i configured as the pause key in my Linux distribution) + combination keys. For example if i want to write the "ñ" character then i press:  ~ n  (pause key plus ~ plus n ). If i do this in Pycharm It just do nothing. I hope you can help me, if no, there is absolutely no problem, thanks!
